# NodeJS: MySQL returns inaccurate decimal values

Tags: mysql, node.js, decimal

I've a MySQL database storing decimal values (DECIMAL(32, 12)).
When I select the values using HeidiSQL, the values are shown correctly (e.g. 15922.638440778302). But when I do the same in NodeJS using the MySQL binding (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), it shows me 15922.63844077830**3**.

My SQL-Query is pretty simple:

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `balances`;
```

Any idea what can cause the difference? Maybe do I need to specify the precision during the MySQL initialization in NodeJS? At the moment, I don't specify anything other than the login credentials:

```
let mysql = require('mysql').createPool({
  host: global.dbconfig['dbhost'],
  database: global.dbconfig['dbname'],
  user: global.dbconfig['dbuser'],
  password: global.dbconfig['dbpass']
})
```

Comment: Since the diff is in about the 17th digit, I deduce that something decided to switch to `DOUBLE`, which has only about 16 digits of precision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add below lines to your `mysql` config.

```
 supportBigNumbers: true
 bigNumberStrings: true
```

Then it becomes:

```
let mysql = require('mysql').createPool({
  host: global.dbconfig['dbhost'],
  database: global.dbconfig['dbname'],
  user: global.dbconfig['dbuser'],
  password: global.dbconfig['dbpass'],
  supportBigNumbers: true,
  bigNumberStrings: true,
})
```

More info on connection options: [docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options)

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that **supportBigNumbers** isn't enough, I also have to enable **bigNumberStrings**.

Comment: `<sarcasm>`Not only do you need to understand MySQL, but you also need to learn the kludges in the intermediate package.`</sarcasm>`